# Error: can't change the style of my title toc, title of my acronyms

Tags: table-of-contents, acronyms

I have created a cls file in order to make my own document style. Everything was working well, however, when I had some code in order to write in differents languages (see in the cls file), it doesn't work anymore. Do you have an idea?

Here a basic example:

```
\documentclass{Internship_Report}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[breaklinks,hidelinks]{hyperref}


\begin{document}


\begin{center}
    \huge{\bfseries{Acknowledgements}}
    \vspace{0.3cm}
\end{center}

\chineseLanguage{非常感谢您} M; \<شكرًا لك أيها>  ; \greekLanguage{Σας ευχαριστώ πoulos} and V

\tableofcontents

\listoffigures

\newpage
\listoftables

\newpage
\chapter{Chap 1}

\chapter{Chap 2}


\end{document}
```

Here the cls file:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}

\ProvidesClass{Internship_Report}[2022/06/02 - Internship Report]

\LoadClass[11pt,twoside]{report}

\RequirePackage{appendix}
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\RequirePackage[toc,acronym]{glossaries}
\RequirePackage{caption}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage[titles]{tocloft}

\RequirePackage{biblatex}



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Geometry 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\RequirePackage{calc}
\RequirePackage[a4paper,top=3.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,outer=1in,inner=1.5in]{geometry}
%\RequirePackage{showframe}

\setlength{\headheight}{13.59999pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Chapter / Section / Appendix 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\RequirePackage{fmtcount}

\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{-23\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \thispagestyle{fancy} \huge\bfseries \thechapter.\space  % Change the size of the chapter title
        %\huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak %\Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
}}

  
\newcommand\appendix@chapter[1]{%
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}
    \refstepcounter{chapter}%
    \def\app@ct{Appendix \@Alph\c@chapter: #1}
    \orig@chapter*{\thispagestyle{fancy}\vspace*{-70\p@} \huge\bfseries \app@ct}      % Change the size of the chapter title
    \markboth{\MakeUppercase{\app@ct}}{\MakeUppercase{\app@ct}}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\normalsize\bfseries\app@ct}%
}
\let\orig@chapter\chapter
\g@addto@macro\appendix{\let\chapter\appendix@chapter}

\newcommand\unappendix{\par
  \setcounter{apdxsection}{\value{section}}%
  \setcounter{section}{\value{savesection}}%
  \setcounter{subsection}{0}%
  \gdef\thesection{\@arabic\c@section}}

\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead} {\vskip 40}{\vskip 20}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{\vskip 40}{\vskip 20}{}{}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\csr}{\textsc{\acrfull{ac:csr}}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\rlc}{\acrshort{ac:rlc}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\sdu}{\acrshort{ac:sdu}}

        
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
{3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
{1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}

\renewcommand\subparagraph{\@startsection{subparagraph}{5}{\parindent}%
{3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus .2ex}%
{1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Table of Contents
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{6pt}

\makeatother

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Hearder / Footer
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\uppercase{\thechapter.~ #1}}{}}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancypagestyle{main}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[LE]{\thepage}
    \fancyhead[RE]{\leftmark}
    \fancyhead[LO]{\leftmark}
    \fancyhead[RO]{\thepage}
    \fancyfoot[LE]{}
    \fancyfoot[RO]{}
    \fancyfoot[LO]{}
    \fancyheadoffset{0cm}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
}


\fancypagestyle{PageNum}{%
    \fancyfoot{}
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[LE]{\thepage}
    \fancyhead[RE]{}
    \fancyhead[LO]{}
    \fancyhead[RO]{\thepage}
    \fancyfoot[LE]{}
    \fancyfoot[RO]{}
    \fancyfoot[LO]{}
    \fancyheadoffset{0cm}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\newcommand{\BlankPageNum}{
    \newpage
    \thispagestyle{PageNum}
    \mbox{}
    \newpage
}

\newcommand{\BlankPage}{
    \newpage
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \mbox{}
    \newpage
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Foreign Languages
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\RequirePackage[LAE,LFE,T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage[greek,main=english]{babel}
\RequirePackage{CJKutf8}
\RequirePackage{arabtex}
\RequirePackage{utf8}

\newcommand{\greekLanguage}[1]{\selectlanguage{greek}#1\selectlanguage{english}}
\newcommand{\chineseLanguage}[1]{\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{gbsn}#1\end{CJK*}}
\newcommand{\arabicLanguage}[1]{\setarab \fullvocalize \transtrue \arabtrue 
    \begin{RLtext}#1\end{RLtext}}
\setcode{utf8}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Contents / Figures / Tables / Bibliography Acronyms names
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\renewcommand\contentsname{\vspace{-2.55cm} \centering \huge\bfseries Table of Contents}
\renewcommand\listfigurename{\vspace{-2.55cm} \centering \huge\bfseries List of Figures}
\renewcommand\listtablename{\vspace{-2.55cm} \centering \huge\bfseries List of Tables}
\renewcommand*{\acronymname}{List of Abbreviations}
```

Comment: Please lookop `\addto\captions<language>` in the manual for `babel`. Babel sets macros like `\contentsname` at the start of the document and thus overwrites what you are doing here.

Comment: I said it before and I'll say it again: _do not add formatting into_ macros like `\contentsname`. It is asking for trouble,